# How can I secure the traefik dashboard using SSL & basic auth?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, traefik

A have traefik set up and working for a 3 node docker swarm on DigitalOcean, and my web apps are being served just fine. I want to secure the traefik dashboard, and have gleaned some info from GitHub issues, but my attempts result in a gateway timeout when trying to access the dashboard.

My compose file is below (auth & url edited for security):

```
version: "3.5"
services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:1.6
    command:
      - --api
      - --docker
      - --docker.watch
      - --docker.swarmmode      
      - --entryPoints=Name:http Address::80
      - --entryPoints=Name:https Address::443 TLS:/run/secrets/el_cert,/run/secrets/el_key,/run/secrets/as_cert,/run/secrets/as_key
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    networks:
      - proxy
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    secrets:
      - as_cert
      - as_key
      - el_cert
      - el_key
    deploy:
      mode: global
      labels:
        - "traefik.frontend.entryPoints=http,https"
        - "traefik.frontend.headers.SSLRedirect=true"
        - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:<hostname>"
        - "traefik.port=8080"
        - "traefik.frontend.auth.basic=<user>:<password>"
      placement:
        constraints: [node.role==manager]
networks:
  proxy:
    external:
      name: proxy
secrets:
  as_cert:
    external: true
  as_key:
    external: true
  el_cert:
    external: true
  el_key:
    external: true
```

BTW If I move the labels out from under deploy it works locally using docker-compose.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following label seems to fix things:

traefik.backend.loadbalancer.swarm=true

I presume the traefik load balancer was getting into some kind of infinite loop. I would be grateful if someone could offer a full explanation!